# How to find the number of lines of the files inside a tar file without extracting

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I have a  tar file, which has lots of csv files in it.
Is there a way to find the number of lines in each csv file without extracting it in linux?

I tried

```
for file in $(tar -tf "$tarfile")
do
  NL=`wc -l < "$file"`
done
```

But it gives error: "No such file or directory".

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in $(tar -tf "$tarfile")
do
    NL=$(tar Oxf "$tarfile" "$file" | wc -l)
done
```

`Oxf` extracts the specified file to stdout.

Comment: Or maybe `tar -tf "tarfile" | while read file ; do tar -Oxf "$tarfile" "$file" | wc -l ; done`

Comment: I replaced t.tar with $tarfile and tried.But got error saying Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: @user1407668 Do you have GNU tar? Run `tar --version`.